# asp.net webforms - how to handle multiple pages with the same name in one web project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, namespaces, asp.net-2.0

I have a web application with several different top-level directories, and some of the pages with different directories have the same name - for example:

```
foo/
  search.aspx
  list.aspx

bar/
  search.aspx
  list.aspx

baz/
  search.aspx
  list.aspx
```

etc.

The problem is that the class names for the code-behind files conflicts - each search is trying to create a class "search".  Is it possible to configure individual directories to use the directory name as part of the class, or perhaps a namespace?

I tried adding a namespace to one of the search pages, and that seemed to work, but that means changing every page, designer, and aspx @Page directive manually.  Is there a way to tell VS2008 to include the directory name as part of the name space?

Answer (score 0):

Use namespaces

```
namespace {Project Name}.foo { public class search {}}
namespace {Project Name}.bar { public class search {}}
```

I don't know if there's a way to manually update each page's inherits properties and the likes